# Is Gibbs free energy the sole determiner for spontaneity?

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics

If a reaction has negative $\Delta G$, can we then say with *certainty* that the reaction will be spontaneous?

Is negative $\Delta G$ the sole determinant for spontaneity?

Comment: please ignore kinetics of reaction in above quo

Comment: What do you mean by reaction? Are we talking about whole conversion of product to reactants? Or are we talking about whether one molecule of reactant converts at all to product?

Comment: @Zhe. I would like to know how does that matter? Well,take my previous comment casually: so that some spontaneous reaction taking too long may not become point of argument.

Comment: Because the microscopic view is governed by likelihood. Likelihood compounds in samples with large numbers. If you're talking about 1 molecule, maybe it's not completely unlikely. If you're talking about a reaction, it's quite possible that given the numbers, you'll never observe an appreciable amount of the product in the sense. Though spontaneity has a very specific definition, so I guess you're right that my previous comment is moot.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For a spontaneous process at ***constant temperature and pressure***, $\Delta G$ ***must*** (emphasis on must) be negative.

Spontaneity of a process , explicitly, depends on the enthalpy change and the entropy change. The Gibbs free energy change includes both these factors to predict the spontaneity of a process.

So, yes it can be said that Gibbs free energy change is the main factor that decides the spontaneity of a process.

Putting into better words, $\Delta G$ being negative is a consequence of a process being spontaneous.

Comment: Technically,  $\Delta G <0$ isn't really necessary.  It's just most probable.  But for any macroscopic sample the huge number of atoms/molecules stacks the odds very heavily.  If this were sports, I would all $\Delta G <0$ a prohibitive favorite.

Comment: To add to what @OscarLanzi said, the requirement that $\Delta G$ be negative for spontaneity is just a Rule of Thumb.

Comment: Then again, you could just argue that "spontaneity" itself is a probabilistic label.

Comment: @orthocresol , you are welcome to edit my answer.

Comment: It's not really important, I was just tacking on to the two previous comments. The entire Second Law is probabilistic in nature, in that a process with $\Delta G < 0$ is *much* more likely to occur than one with $\Delta G > 0$, but it is a point that is only barely related to the question being asked. Your answer is quite fine as it is.

Comment: You might want to mention that different state variables are used to determine spontaneity when "at constant temperature and pressure" does not hold; for instance, Helmholtz free energy for reactions taking place at constant temperature and _volume_ but not constant pressure.

Comment: @zwol. What if pressure and temperature aren't constant, how do we evaulate it then?

Comment: @altosanta I'm sorrry, I don't remember anymore.